# Is it possible to iterate over a python list with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have raw HTML files saved in a list and want to extract the text from each element in the list with the BeautifulSoup function `get.text()`.

Is it possible to iterate over the list with the `get.text()` function?

When I am trying this I am getting the error:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Is there a way to do this?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools 
from collections.abc import Iterable
import pymssql



conn = pymssql.connect(
    host='x',
    port=x,
    user='x',
    password='x',
    database='x'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM x')

text = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall() ]

conn.close()


conn = pymssql.connect(
    host='x',
    port=x,
    user='x',
    password='x',
    database='x'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM x')

t = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall() ]

conn.close()


for line in text:
    soup = bs(text, 'html.parser')

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract() 

autor = soup.get_text()

s = autor.replace('\\n', '')
```

Comment: Try to make your code example smaller. Who cares about the fact that your getting the text from a database? Initialize it directly in your code, e.g. `text = [b"...", ...]` or `text = ["...", ...]`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Will consider this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole text list to BeautifulSoup.

Try:

```py
for line in text:
    soup = bs(line, 'html.parser')
```

Then you probably want to add the rest of the code inside this for loop so you run it for each "line" that I understand is a whole html string.